# How can I explicitly write a vector required to rotate another vector in 3D space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with circumcenter $O$ ($\vec{O}$ will be the zero vector). Suppose I have a point $P$ such that $OP$ is perpendicular to the plane defined by $ABC$. I want to rotate the vector $\vec{P}$ to point towards $A$, but to consider sign (if $P$ is into the page, it should point towards $A$; if it is out of the page, then it should point away from $A$). In other words, I want to find a vector $\vec{V}$ such that $\vec{P} \times \vec{V} = k\vec{A}$, where $k\vec{A}$ is the rotation of $P$. I know that $\vec{V}$ is a unit vector in the plane of $ABC$ perpendicular to $A$, but I have two problems. First, there are two such vectors, and my choice will affect the sign of the result. Second, I need $\vec{V}$ in an explicit form of the vectors $\vec{A}$, $\vec{B}$, and/or $\vec{C}$. It is fine to include manipulations of these vectors such as using the different vectorial products, to assume an orientation for $ABC$, and to include the circumradius of $ABC$ if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

$$\vec W=(\vec B-\vec A)\times(\vec C-\vec A)$$

is a vector perpendicular to the plane of the triangle. Then

$$\vec V=\vec W\times\vec A$$

is within the plane and perpendicular to $\vec A$. Normalize that to unit length:

$$\hat V=\frac{\vec V}{\lVert\vec V\rVert}$$

and you are almost done. The orientation of this vector here depends on the orientation of the triangle. Give it a try whether it's the correct orientation in one sample case. If not, flip the sign of the result, or swap $\vec B$ and $\vec C$ in the first line.